# Will a grade school and high school steal students from my university?

Tags: simcity-2013

This question is related to this other question: [Once you build a University, can the high school and community college be safely closed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107972/once-you-build-a-university-can-the-high-school-and-community-college-be-safely)

I find that my University is routinely under-used, while I have two grade schools that are routinely close-to-full.

Has anyone experimented with disabling their grade schools?  Does the university fill up?  Or are the student pools entirely different?

Update: I tried powering off my grade schools and high school during the night (community college was already off).  Around 4pm of the that day, the University crossed the 1,000 students threshold.

So I think this is evidence for the "single student" pool hypothesis (which is weird I suppose).

Comment: I do notice that the population view shows "kids" and "students" as being different.  So is a "student" someone that goes to college (community vs university)?

Comment: i noticed that my fully upgraded grade school was full. I built a highschool and now the gradeschool is around half capacity.

Comment: I do not believe Grade School will steal from Universities, but High School might affect the number of people who go to University - I will test

Comment: Is the root of this question trying to figure out how to do research faster? If that is the case the group of people I play with have found that just having more students, regardless of what level, appeared to have a positive effect on university research projects.. But since that was not part of your original question I did not feel it was worthy of being put in an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no - universities rely on your city's mass transit system and road network to allow your students to get to it. School buses will not drop students off at a university, therefore only students that can arrive using mass transit or a car will go to a university.

Grade schools and high schools on the other hand provide their own transport, it still relies on your road network but is separate from your mass transit. These schools will pick up students from school bus stops, and students will wait for the buses at the school stops provided that the stop is within walking distance (highlighted by the dots along the road when you place the stop, or detailed on the education overview).

One of the main challenges I faced while trying to build a comprehensive education system that enrolled all students was transport, sending out fleets of buses would gridlock my road network during school hours - if your students can't get to a school they will unenroll.

I have written up a comprehensive answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108926/27134)

Comment: Doesn't SimCity send students to colleges and university based upon the house income level they come from? I don't think shutting down colleges will automatically send low income students to university. They must first complete college to raise their income level, and then they can go to university. The alternative is to increase the land value for those homes so there are no low income students.

Comment: No - colleges are used as a replacement to universities, it pretty much states this in the tooltip, but with testing it shows that placing a university and a college next to each other has no effect on enrolment rate but reduces the number of students attending each in comparison to only having one of the buildings in the city.