# What is the formula for converting population to residential agents (workers, shoppers, students)?

Tags: simcity-2013

I learned in [another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108894/how-do-you-provide-more-workers-to-your-city) that the population number can be much higher than the number of residential agents (workers, shoppers, students) in the city.

**What is the formula for converting population to residential agents?** For example, if a city has 100k population, how many residential agents are in that city?

Comment: The formula actually goes the other way around...  each building has a specific number of agents, and the cosmetic population figure is computed from that number of agents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The calculation you're asking for actually works the other way around in SimCity, the number of agents is taken and then run through a function to return a 'fudged' population figure.

The function in game that returns the population is as follows;

```
simcity.GetFudgedPopulation = function (a) {
    a = "undefined" !== typeof a ? a : simcity.gGlobalUIHandler.mLastPopulation;
    if (500 >= a)
        return a;
    if (40845 < a)
        return Math.floor(8.25 * a);
    a = Math.pow(a - 500, 1.2) + 500;
    return Math.floor(a)
};
```

This works out as follows;

- if `a` is less than/equal to 500, return `a`
- if `a` is greater than 501 but less than 40845, return `(a-500)^1.2 + 500`
- if `a` is greater than 40845, return `8.25 * a`

Here is a graph of how the actual population relates to the displayed population;

[image: graph]

To work out the number of agents that makes up your displayed population, you would use one the following formula ([courtesy of OrigamiRobot@The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8531301#8531301)), depending on the size of your population;

if `population` is:

- less than/equal to 500, the population value is the number of agents active in the city
- greater than 501 but less than 336971, use `(population - 500)^(5/6) + 500 = a`
- greater than 336971, use `population/8.25`

This would return the number of actual agents present for your current population.