# How to provide workers, shops and freight in my simcity5?

Tags: simcity-2013

[image]

I have all those available jobs, all this population, I need a lot of shops and I also need 1000 freight... what can I do to solve this situation? thanks

Comment: How to get more freight: 
http://community.simtropolis.com/topic/54680-shoppers-vs-workers-now-with-added-tourists/

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the per-wealth demand bars visible in the Zoning menu?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the worker/population imbalance is described in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/109072/9192).  Disregard the population number.

Aside from that, you are trying to balance RCI.  This is an ideal goal, but imbalanced RCI also has value as it indicates in which direction your city can grow.  When I play, I try to imbalance RCI in particular ways to encourage growth.

### Workers vs Jobs

Buildings with jobs activate when the minimum worker count is reached and can accept workers until the maximum is reached.  LW LD Industry accepts a maximum of 14 workers (10 low and 4 medium) but will open at full production capacity with any 6 workers.  Filling the 8 extra jobs doesn't generate more freight or tax, but it does provide residential wages.  This buffer allows your residential to grow without precise management of available jobs.  The game tolerates a certain level of open jobs.

Conversely, the game also tolerates a certain level of unemployment.  As long as residential buildings aren't running out of money, it doesn't matter whether workers work.  MW and HW tolerate unemployment more as those workers earn more money.

In my cities, I tend to keep up to 40% extra jobs for LW.  I try to employ at least half of MW and HW, or have up to 40% extra jobs at these levels too.

### Shoppers and Goods

Commercial buildings sell goods to stay in business (each good sold generates 1 unit of profit).  These buildings also accept freight and sell souvenirs for bonus profit.  C buildings can survive and grow just selling goods without the bonus profit, but you need to sell all the goods (check commercial view at 5 am).

Shoppers bring happiness back to residential buildings.  Shoppers that visit parks are bringing the same happiness back as shoppers which buy goods, but those park shoppers are represented as unsatisfied in the population detail screen.  As long as the residential buildings aren't running out of happiness, you don't need to satisfy all the shoppers.

I tend to satisify 50-70% of shoppers through goods: If there are 1000 shoppers, I'll have 600 goods and 400 unsatisfied shoppers.

### Freight and Freight Orders

Commercial buildings accept freight for bonus profit.  Other buildings accept freight for no direct benefit to that building.  When any building accepts frieght, the industrial truck brings profit back to the industrial building.  This allows the industrial to survive and grow.

All freight produced must be shipped (100%).  No freight orders need to be filled.  An unfilled freight order just means you could add/grow more industrial to get jobs and taxes.

In my cities, I build a freight warehouse to accept freight near the industrial buildings and expand it if I need more freight orders.  I don't concern myself with the freight orders of the commercial buildings.